# Clearing the contents of a file in Java without instantiating the BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

Is there any way to delete/clear the contents of a file without instantiating the BufferedWriter or deleting the File?

Comment: Yeah open up the file with an editor and delete all of it lol

Comment: You could just instantiate and close a `FileOutputStream`.  Or do you want to actually overwrite the contents, in which case this is a completely different question.

Comment: Why is deleting the file not an option, that is a arbitrary restriction that makes no sense?

Comment: I can't just open the file on an editor and delete them manually. I'm running them on a batch job and that's a tedious job. I'm also opening the file on another class so the writing process is being done on 2 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Easily you can do it like this:

```
File file = new File("Path/to/the/file");
file.delete(); // delete the file
file.createNewFile(); // create a new and empty file
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a solution wherein you don't need to delete and recreate the file.

Comment: It is the fastest way to do, if you want to clear the content, then you need to do a lot of things. If it is a large file, then need looping to delete and so on.